# Magical beings have managed to tessellate

Tags: calculus

Magical beings have managed to tessellate an entire plan, indefinite, in the way the following figure shows a detail:

[image: picture with black and white hexagons]

They have done it by assembling pieces all the same, each of which was formed by a few white or black hexagons.

What fraction of the entire surface of the plane is black?

Comment: calculus tag?!? Just count!

Comment: Defining a "fraction of the entire surface" can be a tricky thing. It's simpler to look at just one of the identical pieces that was used to tessellate the plane, and say what fraction of that piece is black.

Comment: One eighth, assuming that the question even makes sense (Per David K.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may tessellate the plane with this shape made of 8 hexagons (only look at the whole hexagons in the image):

As there is one black hexagon in each shape, the percentage of black hexagons in the limit is $\frac{1}{8}$

But as other have said, it is not trivial to rigorously define "the percentage of black hexagons" in an infinite plane.

[image]